# What is the inverse of the following function

Tags: functions, inverse

what is the inverse of

$$G(x):=\exp(-\exp(-x))?$$

Comment: For future reference, in order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 2):

$$y=\exp(-\exp(-x))$$
$$\ln(y)=-\exp(-x)$$
$$-\ln(y)=\exp(-x)$$
$$\ln(-\ln(y))=-x$$
$$-\ln(-\ln(y))=x$$

So the inverse function is $$G^{-1}(x)=-\ln(-\ln(x))$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $y=e^{-e^{-x}}$ then $\ln y=-e^{-x}\implies -\ln y= e^{-x}\implies \ln((-\ln y))=-x\implies x=-\ln((-\ln y))$